# Find numbers and letters in a vector

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a vector composed by these strings:

```
10I/V/F/R, 16E, 20R/M/T/I, 24I, 32I, 33F/I/V, 36I/L/V,45R, 46I/L/V, 48M/V, 53L,
54L/M/V, 60E, 63P, 71V/T/I,73C/S/T/A, 82A/F/I/S/T/M/L/C, 84A/C/V,85V, 88D/T/S, 89M/V/Q/T, 90M
```

And I have another like that:

```
10F, 20M, 33F, 82A, 89Q, 93K
```

I would like to verify if each string of my second vector exists in the first. In this example, it is true for the first five, because for each number, the letter associated is present. I would like to receive as answer the numbers of strings that match, in this case, 5.

Comment: Cool.  What have you tried?

Comment: The two ideas provided here worked!

Answer (score 1):

We can transform the search strings into regexes and then match each one against the target vector. Since you want the number of search strings that matched, we can count how many search strings had at least one match in the target vector.

```
sum(lengths(lapply(sub('^([0-9]+)([a-zA-Z])$','^\\1.*\\2',b),grep,a))>0L);
## [1] 5
```

**Data**

```
a <- c('10I/V/F/R','16E','20R/M/T/I','24I','32I','33F/I/V','36I/L/V,45R','46I/L/V','48M/V',
'53L','54L/M/V','60E','63P','71V/T/I,73C/S/T/A','82A/F/I/S/T/M/L/C','84A/C/V,85V','88D/T/S',
'89M/V/Q/T','90M');
b <- c('10F','20M','33F','82A','89Q','93K');
```

Answer (score 1):

First we extract all digits in `v1` and store them in `l1` and we extract all alpha and store them in `l2`. We then combine the two in `lst` using `mapply()` and `paste0()`. Finally, we loop over `v2` and `sum()` all matches of `grepl()` returning `TRUE`

```
library(stringi)

l1  <- stri_extract_all_regex(v1, "[:digit:]+")
l2  <- stri_extract_all_regex(v1, "[:alpha:]")
lst <- mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x, y), l1, l2)

sum(sapply(v2, function(x) grepl(x, lst)))
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] 5
```

---

**Data**

```
v1 <- c("10I/V/F/R", "16E", "20R/M/T/I", "24I", "32I", "33F/I/V", 
        "36I/L/V", "45R", "46I/L/V", "48M/V", "53L", "54L/M/V", 
        "60E", "63P", "71V/T/I", "73C/S/T/A", "82A/F/I/S/T/M/L/C", 
        "84A/C/V", "85V", "88D/T/S", "89M/V/Q/T", "90M")

v2 <- c("10F", "20M", "33F", "82A", "89Q", "93K");
```

Comment: @LetíciaRaposo Glad it helped :)